# javascript or jquery fileSize

Tags: javascript, jquery, activexobject, filesize

I was looking all over the web how i can get the file size on the client side
so i found a few examples
the first example was

```
$(this)[0].files[0].fileSize
```

but unfortunately it does not working in ie

so i found this example

```
function getSize(){
var myFSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var filepath = document.upload.file.value;
var thefile = myFSO.getFile(filepath);
var size = thefile.size;
alert(size + " bytes");
}
```

which is suppose to work in ie but i heard it has security problems and i don't know if it work in all browsers..

so , i need to know what i can use in javascript client side to get the file size..
e.g : file from input type file
thank you for helping.

Comment: The file size of what exactly - a remote URL? A local file?

Comment: You will not get one single script to work across all browsers. I vote to use your first method, and simply disallow the functionality in IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript cannot access any information about local files. This is done deliberately for security reasons.

`ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");` is an IE-only construct and will not work across browsers.